# SPSS style "Clustered" bar chart of counts in multiple columns with python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, charts

I have some categorical data

```
example_data = {'Role':['Teacher', 'Teacher', 'Student', 'Admin', 'Student'],
    'Preference': ['Online', 'Blended', 'Blended', 'Face-to-face', 'Face-to-face'],
    'Location' : ['City', 'City', 'City', 'Rural', 'Rural']} 
    
df = pd.DataFrame(example_data, columns=['Role','Preference','Location'])
```

I would like to make a "clustered" bar chart, of the counts of `df['Role']`and `df['Preference']` such that preference is on the x axis, the y axis is the count for each preference, and each bar is clustered by role. In SPSS this is called a clustered bar chart and looks like

[image: spss clustered bar Graph]

Now this example is obviously from fake data, and I'm not worried about the styling, but I have tried various `groupby()` and `value_counts()` permutations and I'm still missing something.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Preference'], df['Role']).plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to shift it from count to %?